# How to hide columns that are not returned with dataset results using function IsMissing in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, dynamic-columns

I have a stored procedure which drops either 1 or 2 columns from the result set. In my SSRS report, I have all possible columns that may come from the result set as dataset fields. I am trying to use the IsMissing function to change the column visibility, but it is not working. How can I make this functionality work?

I tried using examples from 
https://sqlserverbi.blog/tag/hide-columns/
and 
https://www.allaboutmssql.com/2013/01/ssrs-ismissing-visibility-function.html
where I right click the column, select Column Visibility and add an expression to the Show or hide based on an expression line.

Here is how I have been trying to use the expressions:
When I want to hide 2 of the columns I use:

```
=Fields!LINE_30_A.IsMissing And Fields!LINE_30_B.IsMissing
```

and when I want to hide only one of them I use:

```
=Fields!LINE_30.IsMissing
```

I have also tried the expressions like this:

```
=IIF(Fields!LINE_30_A.IsMissing And Fields!LINE_30_B.IsMissing,True,False)
```

I ran my stored procedure in a way that has dropped 1 of the columns from the result set. In this case the expression `Fields!LINE_30.IsMissing` should have been evaluated and I should be seeing the columns for Fields!LINE_30_A and Fields!LINE_30_B. But I only see the column for Fields!LINE_30 (which shouldn't be showing at all) and the other 2 columns are hidden. I also receive these 2 warnings:

> 1) Warning [rsErrorReadingDataSetField] The dataset ‘DataSet1’ contains a definition for the Field ‘LINE_30’. The data extension returned an error during reading the field. There is no data for the field at position 11.
>
> 2) Warning [rsMissingFieldInDataSet] The dataset ‘DataSet1’ contains a definition for the Field ‘LINE_30’. This field is missing from the returned result set from the data source.

Comment: Why not just return all the columns with null values? Seems less likely to cause issues...

Comment: I would but I need to actually hide the columns. Am I misunderstanding how the IsMissing function is supposed to work?

Comment: Thats the easy bit... either detect when the value of the column is null, or add another column to your dataset which tells you which columns to show. But actually conditionally returning the column from your SP is going to more complex.

Comment: So at the end of my SP I just do a quick check of a value and do an ALTER TABLE and DROP the needed columns. When the result set gets to the report, the report has everything that it needs to do what it has to do. I think? Am I able to achieve my goal without using an extra column or setting all of the row of the column/s to be dropped to NULL?

Comment: Apparently your last line of code using the `IIF` statement should work. I imagine the warnings are just warning and don't stop anything from working. Try swapping your True & False around - I find the SSRS visibility logic is sometimes reversed.

Comment: That was it! Thanks a bunch!